# Count occurrence of elements in map during creation

Tags: hash-map, go

This code works, but it's so ugly, so I was hesitant to put it on display.
There must be a nicer/easier way to achieve this.
The main issue is to count each unique occurrence during runtime when the object creation takes time.

Input:

```
1190 W X 1648 H X 14 T
S
1190 W X 1254 H X 14 T
S
1190 W X 1254 H X 14 T
S
1190 W X 1254 H X 14 T
S
1190 W X 1254 H X 14 T
S
1190 W X 1648 H X 14 T
```

I read each word by word, I need to extract from this data, occurrences, plus number of times each elements occurs.

```
func CreateGlassBoxNew(db *gorm.DB, boxID uint, internalName string, glassBoxData []byte) {
    m := make(map[string]Measurement)
    var outerList []string
    var innerList []int
    var index = 0
    var count = 0
    var appendStr string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(string(glassBoxData)))
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if scanner.Text() == "S" || scanner.Text() == "W" || scanner.Text() == "H" || scanner.Text() == "T" || scanner.Text() == "X" {
            continue
        }

        appendStr += scanner.Text() + "-"
        innerList = append(innerList, addMeasurementInt(scanner.Text()))

        index++
        if index == 3 {
            dump.P(innerList)
            count++
            fmt.Println(count)
            m[appendStr] = Measurement{
                Width:      innerList[0],
                Height:     innerList[1],
                Thicknes:   innerList[2],
                Quantity:   count,
                GlassBoxID: boxID,
            }
            innerList = nil
            outerList = append(outerList, appendStr)

            appendStr = ""
            index = 0

        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        dump.P(err)
    }

    dump.P(m)

    occurenceMap := CountOccurence(outerList)

    var finalList []Measurement
    for key, element := range m {
        finalList = append(finalList, Measurement{
            Width:      element.Width,
            Height:     element.Height,
            Thicknes:   element.Thicknes,
            Quantity:   occurenceMap[key],
            GlassBoxID: boxID,
        })
    }
    dump.P(finalList)
}
```

the final result ready for db insert, looks like this, here is the `quantity` variable set.

```
[]models.Measurement [ #len=2
  models.Measurement {
    Width: int(1190),
    Height: int(1648),
    Thicknes: int(14),
    Quantity: int(2),
    GlassBoxID: uint(3436),
    BluePrintName: *string<nil>,
  },
  models.Measurement {
    Width: int(1190),
    Height: int(1254),
    Thicknes: int(14),
    Quantity: int(4),
    GlassBoxID: uint(3436),
    BluePrintName: *string<nil>,
  },
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be simplified greatly be leveraging the fact that your input data:

1. Is coming all at once (is a `[]byte` not a `io.Reader`)
2. At least appears very structured

I am thinking that the who scanner loop can bet replaced by:

```golang
glassBoxes := strings.Split(string(glassBoxData), "\nS\n")

    for i := range glassBoxes {
        vals := strings.Split(glassBoxes[i], " ")
        if len(vals) != 8 {
            log.Fatal("invalid row: " + glassBoxes[i])
        }
        width, err := strconv.Atoi(vals[0])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("bad width " + err.Error())
        }
        height, err := strconv.Atoi(vals[3])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("bad height " + err.Error())
        }
        thickness, err := strconv.Atoi(vals[6])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("bad thickness " + err.Error())
        }
        quantity := i + 1

        //construct you `Measurement` here and load it into 
        // the collecting slice
        fmt.Printf("w: %d h: %d t: %d count: %d\n", width, height, thickness, quantity)
    }
```